# 'router-outlet' is not a known element while executing ng build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript, router-outlet

I am getting below error while doing `ng build --prod`. It works fine in `ng build`.

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
1 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

I am using RouterModule in `app.module.ts` file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from  '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {NgbDropdown, NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FilterPipe } from './dashboard/filter.pipe';

import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe';
import { LastseenDevicesComponent } from './modal/lastseen-devices/lastseen-devices.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    TimeAgoPipe,
    FilterPipe,
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ NgbDropdown],
  //schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
  //providers: [ NgbDropdown,DataService, UtilService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`app-routing.module.ts` file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
 
const routes: Routes = [
 
 {
 path: '', pathMatch: 'full' ,component: DashboardComponent,  
  },
 
];
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is `main.ts` file

```
import 'hammerjs';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

`app.component.ts` file

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Project1';
}
```

app.component.html file only has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. `Environment` folder has two files `environment.prod.ts` and `environment.ts` file.

`Angular.json` file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "AirwatchProject1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Project1",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ]          
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "disableHostCheck": true,
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Project1:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Project1:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Project1:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json",
              "tsconfig.worker.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Project1:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Project1:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Project1",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "80627-93f7438a70dd"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this ?

*Angular CLI: 10.0.5
Node: 12.18.3*

Comment: little more code please. have you put some thing in export in app module?

Comment: @AdnanAhmed - Please check my updated question.

Comment: You do not need to import router module in your `AppComponent`. Are you importing `RouterModule` elsewhere?

Comment: @David - I am not using anywhere except given file `app-routing.module.ts`. Please check my updated question. Using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html` file Thank you.

Comment: What if you replace your AppRoutingModule declaration  with `export const AppRoutingModule : ModuleWithProviders<RouterModule> = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);`? Does it change anything?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Angular v10? Also you could check your code with WebStorm. If any component/directive misses an import it would suggest importing it. Perhaps IDE's static analysis could fix this

Comment: @Sergey - This configuration I am using _Angular CLI: 10.0.5 Node: 12.18.3_.

Comment: I'm not asking of CLI I'm asking of packages

Comment: Is it your problem resolved?

Comment: @AmanGojariya - Not yet. I have handed over to senior developers.

Comment: @R15, I am also facing the same issue, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AppRoutingModule` should already import and export the `RouterModule`. So you should remove `RouterModule` from your `AppModule` imports.

I assume your `AppRoutingModule` looks something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Route[] = [...]

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

On a sidenote I also highly discourage the use of `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`

Comment: appRoutes, how to get ?

Comment: @R15 It would be easier if your question included the content of `AppRoutingModule`. And just maybe - a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MikeS. - Adding it.

Comment: R15 I don't see anything wrong in your `AppRoutingModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Import the `RouterModule` in the module where you declare the component that gives the error. For anything related to routine in the HTML, import the `RouterModule`

Comment: `src-->app--> app.component.html`, this `html` file has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Now where should I import `Router`. I do not other module file except `app.module`

Comment: AppModule it it then

Comment: What do you mean by `AppModule it it then`. Do I need to add one more module file explicitly?