# How to generate production build for Angular application

Tags: angular, production-environment

I have developed an `Angular` application and released on `Sandbox` machine. Now I want to release it on `Enterprise` virtual machine.

I want to generate production build for Enterprise VM. Right now my `dist` size is 174 MB, I am assuming it reduce in prod build, am I correct? I am thinking I need to run first `ng build --prod` and then `ng serve --prod` and take the `dist` out.

In my project there is environment folder with two file `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`, what should I do with these two.

If I try `ng build --prod` getting errors here
['router-outlet' is not a known element while executing ng build --prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844526/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element-while-executing-ng-build-prod)

How should I generate production build?

Comment: Did you import RouterModule into your AppModule?

Comment: @Timothy - Yes, I tried with too, in imports. still facing same issue. please check the link to another question. FYI, in app.module.ts file I added.

Comment: Can you please share your app-routing module code and app.module.ts code?

Comment: @AmanGojariya - Could you please check the link provided in question. There I have added full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully generated my production build. For production we do not need to use `ng serve --prod`.

First we need to execute `ng build --prod` and then `ng serve`.

`ng build --prod` is doing `minification` of our `dist` folder and `ng serve` just starting our `project/server`.

I have facing few issue related memory [heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558989/node-js-heap-out-of-memory/66604217#66604217) for that I needed run below command run [these commands in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598952/ineffective-mark-compacts-near-heap-limit-allocation-failed-windows-angular/66604321#66604321).